# render template Rails.root in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

Im need render this remplate with Rails.root

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:template => '#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/posts/repost_new'))%>
```

but I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing template #{Rails.root}...more
```

I have the file **repost_new.html.erb** in views posts directory...

I have **repost_new** method in **posts_controller.rb**

What is the problem :S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use double quotes instead of single ones. Single quoted strings are not interpolated in Ruby.